# Record Screen with sound using AS3 or Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I am developing a piano app and i want to record the screen together with the sound for a user to record a piece. Can i do this using AS3 or Flash builder? how?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible as far as I know to record the screen to a movie using flash. However, there might be ways to get around it - it all depends on how you do things.

You could take a series of "screenshots" of your app using the draw function and a bitmapData object, encode that to a series of images and do something with them. You would also need to manually capture the sound by generating waveform data and sending it to a sound object (and saving it at the same time) instead of playing it directly. This is not a trivial undertaking however, and it might be easier to build your own "midi" format;

Every time the user pressed a piano button, add an "action" to an array (what key was pressed, what frame/time it happened, any other information you might need). Then you have the user save that array to a file and when they want to "view the song", use the data to "replay" the song (just read every item from the array and fake user input from the data).

Comment: actions array seems a better option)

Comment: but this will be more helpful if can add some codes as basis. =)

Answer (score 0):

No i don't think so, the api for record screen is no public(Adobe used this functionality with Adobe Connect) but is no sharing the API